# Dealing with root powers of variable to some other power

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, variable

In my code I keep coming across terms like this in the output $(w^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ that mathematica refuses to simplify. I have tried using a simplifying assumption such as $w\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ but it still returns the same result.

Is there a command I can use to simplify results like these?

Comment: Please post the minimal code that generates such output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
FullSimplify[PowerExpand[(w^3)^(1/3)]]
(* w *)
```

- [PowerExpand](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)
- [FullSimplify](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

Comment: Yep.  Just what I was about to post.  Even `Simplify[PowerExpand[(w^3)^(1/3)]]` works.